# Tomcat7 catalina errors

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I am trying to run my java servlet on Tomcat7. But when I try to deploy and run I get this error below:

```
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh run
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0
[2015-01-21 06:46:53,383] Artifact app:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat7/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat7/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1381 ms
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 144 ms
Connected to server
[2015-01-21 06:46:55,522] Artifact app:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2015-01-21 06:46:59,629] Artifact app:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

I tried looking the configurations (`catalina.properties`) and it doesn't seem to have any issues. The configuration (unimportant parts are omitted) is:

```
package.access=sun.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.tomcat.,org.apache.jasper.
package.definition=sun.,java.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.tomcat.,org.apache.jasper.
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/common/classes,${catalina.home}/common/*.jar
server.loader=${catalina.home}/server/classes,${catalina.home}/server/*.jar
```

I don't really know where else to check or do. What could be wrong with this?

Comment: Have you checked the log files of `logs` sub-directory? For example the `catalina.'date'.log`?

Comment: @Tom you mean `/var/log/tomcat7/`?

Comment: If the logs are there, then yes. On some installations, they are in `[tomcat-root-directory]/logs`.

Comment: @Tom I checked the logs there but there aren't any logs for the last 12 hours since that output was received.

Answer (score 0):

These are the only errors in your log file:

```
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 21, 2015 6:46:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

They indicate that your web application didn't start up properly. You'll need to look in another log file for why. Look at every other log files that are in the same directory as catalina.out (or wherever you found the above logs) for anything that happened around 18:46:59 today.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing there. I checked every file. This output is gathered from the IDE's console (IntelliJ tomcat deployment)

Comment: What if you launch Tomcat from the command-line? Perhaps IntelliJ is doing something weird with the environment.